# all: unset removes contenteditable

Tags: html, css

I have a span class in my project which should only have the propertys of it's parent. So I set all:unset. But this element should be editable as well. And it looks like that all:unset also removes the ability to edit the content of the element.

CSS:

```css
.mytext{
  all:unset;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="mytext" contenteditable="true">Editable Text</span></h1>
```

So is there a way to use all:unset and contenteditable="true"?

EDIT: And yes, I have to use it this way. I can't add the contenteditable attribute to the parent. The reason is that the content of h1 (in this case) will be added dynamically. The span element will contain some additional data attributes which I need. I can't add these attributes to the parent element, because I don't know which element will be the parent.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround for know, but I still would like to know if there is an easier way. For now I take the data attributes from the span element with jquery and add it to the parent element, then I take the content from the span element and replace the parent content with it.

Answer (score 2):

How about a `:not()` selector?

```css
.mytext:not([contenteditable="true"]) {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="mytext" contenteditable="true">Editable Text</span></h1>
```

Comment: Awesome. I should have known this by myself, but it didn't occurred to me. Thank you!

Comment: Ok it looks like I was celebrating to soon. This would apply the all:unset only to elements which have no contententeditable attribute... but I need the all:unset property apply to those as well. But I have a workaround with jquery... this would do it for the moment. But maybe there is still an easier way for this.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today when working with a bookmarklet, which excluded jquery as a viable solution.

I have found that the source of the issue is that `all: unset` or `all: initial` also override some browser-specific properties. In this case, setting

```
-moz-user-modify: read-write;
-webkit-user-modify: read-write;
```

fixed the issue, at least in Chrome.